# Iframe problem with IE6 & IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, layout, iframe, cross-browser

I'm experiencing difficulties getting my iframe to display correctly in IE6 & IE7.
[www.e-g-t.nl](http://www.e-g-t.nl)
I think IE has the height of the iframe stretched to far beyond the 400px height I set it to be, and the content is vertically centered.

I'm not an expert at css or html for that matter and don't seem to get it right. In IE8 though, the problem doesn't seem to exist. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: There are no iframes in the source of the page...?

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this works:
http://strcpy.com/262.

it works in IE8 because of its "Compatibility Mode"/quirks mode...